# Rollback if null

Tags: sql, rollback

I was reading articles about rollback transaction and can't find something like I need. Assume I have a user table. User can update his/her records but I want to rollback if entered value is null. I know there are lots of simple ways to do this like checking with c# if it is null and things like that but point in here is understanding rollback. How can I use rollback with if(null) code ?

Comment: Why not simply NOT NULL columns?

Comment: Like I said there are lots of ways of doing this and not null is one of them but I need an example of rollback with if. It can be something like 'if age < 40 then rollback'. Checking null was just an example @jarlh

Comment: Please label with what language you are using and any code you have attempted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rollback is used with a transaction, a rollback restores the state to what it was when begin tran was executed.

```
BEGIN TRAN 'tran1'
       INSERT INTO Whatever table...
      IF(... check for null)
      BEGIN 
        ROLLBACK TRAN 'tran1'
        RETURN 0
      END
COMMIT TRAN 'tran1'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways. First, if your checks are just on one column, use the `check` constraint on the column definition:

```
 create table test (
      age int check (age > 40),
      ...  
 );
```

Fore more complex constraints, you will need `triggers`. The kind of triggers available depends on the technology (oracle, sql server, mysql). Inside a *before insert* or *before update* trigger, you can generate an exception, which will automatically end up the transaction (equivalent to a rollback). Here is a mysql example:

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists trg_trigger_test_ins //
create trigger trg_trigger_test_ins before insert on test
for each row
begin
    declare msg varchar(128);
    if new.age <= 40 then
        set msg = concat('MyTriggerError: age incorrect : ', cast(new.id as char));
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
    end if;
end
//
```

Finally, you can start a *transaction*, make your changes, then decide if you want to *commit* or *rollback*.

Answer (score 0):

To rollback transaction you must first start transaction. As a rule DBMS have implicit transactions, if nothing specified, every statement or batch starts and commits/rollbacks it's own transaction. Or you may explicitly define transaction bounds.

So if you need any (implicit, explicit) transaction which involves setting given column to NULL to fail and rollback then just define constraint on this column.

Alternatively you may want only some explicit transactions rollback depending on this column value and some other conditions. So you should explicitly have this check in your code.